# Appending the element of a list to the left or right of the iterator to another list

Tags: python

I'm examining a string and looking for the occurrence of a specific word. If the iterator matches that word, I would like to append the element that is directly to the left or to the right of it.

I've tried using enumerate, but I just keep appending the element at the end of the list.

```
complete_word_list = ['3', 'May', '.', 'Bistritz', '.', 'Left', 'Munich', 'at', '8:35', 'P.', 'M.', ',', 'on', '1st', 'May', ',', 'arriving', 'atVienna', 'early', 'next', 'morning', ';', 'should', 'have', 'arrived', 'at', '6:46', ',', 'but', 'train', 'dracula', 'anhour', 'late']

dracula_list = ['dracula','Dracula']
nearby_words = []

for i in complete_word_list:

    if i in dracula_list and i in complete_word_list:

        dracula_list.append(complete_word_list[i:-1])
```

Ideally, I would receive

```
['train', 'anhour']
```

Comment: Does the code works? If I'm not mistake `i` is a string, or I'm missing something?

Comment: no need to do `i in complete_word_list` inside of `for i in complete_word_list`

Comment: I suggest you join the list and look at regex `import re` for what you need, it seems to be the right package for your purpose. In reality, your example doesn't describe what you want to do with edge cases (what if the word "dracula" is first or last?) I would suggest using `zip` with sliced lists

Comment: @DanielMesejo The code "works" sorry forgot to say that, but it doesn't actually append anything to the nearby_words list.

Comment: @SebastianGoslin but you never called `nearby_words.append()` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work, although doesn't account for the edge cases I mentioned. I would include an elif if those are of concern to you.

```
complete_word_list = ['3', 'May', '.', 'Bistritz', '.', 'Left', 'Munich', 'at', '8:35', 'P.', 'M.', ',', 'on', '1st', 'May', ',', 'arriving', 'atVienna', 'early', 'next', 'morning', ';', 'should', 'have', 'arrived', 'at', '6:46', ',', 'but', 'train', 'dracula', 'anhour', 'late']

dracula_list = ['dracula','Dracula']

nearby_words = []
for w1, w2, w3 in zip(complete_word_list[0:-1], complete_word_list[1:-1], complete_word_list[1:]):
    if w2 in dracula_list:
        nearby_words.append((w1, w3))
```

Comment: This is perfect, I also took your advice on `import re` I'm currently constructing a pattern to match it now that'll take care of the edge cases. I'll post it once its done to anyone who has the same question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `range` instead, which will give control over your indices in order to check whether they are within bound so that you will add the respecting element to the `nearby_words` list:

```
complete_word_list = ['3', 'May', '.', 'Bistritz', '.', 'Left', 'Munich', 'at', '8:35', 'P.', 'M.', ',', 'on', '1st', 'May', ',', 'arriving', 'atVienna', 'early', 'next', 'morning', ';', 'should', 'have', 'arrived', 'at', '6:46', ',', 'but', 'train', 'dracula', 'anhour', 'late']

dracula_list = ['dracula','Dracula']
nearby_words = []

for i in range(len(complete_word_list)):
    if complete_word_list[i] in dracula_list:
        if i >= 1: # Check if there is an element to the left to append it.
            nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[i-1])
        if i <= len(complete_word_list)-2: # Check if there is an element to the right to append it.
            nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[i+1])

print(nearby_words)
```

Output:

```
['train', 'anhour']
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it's easier to use the index of the word to find as opposed to looping over the list.

```
complete_word_list = ['3', 'May', '.', 'Bistritz', '.', 'Left', 'Munich', 'at', '8:35', 'P.', 'M.', ',', 'on', '1st', 'May', ',', 'arriving', 'atVienna', 'early', 'next', 'morning', ';', 'should', 'have', 'arrived', 'at', '6:46', ',', 'but', 'train', 'dracula', 'anhour', 'late']

dracula_list = ['dracula','Dracula']
nearby_words = []

for i in dracula_list:
    if i in complete_word_list: #if word was found in list
        found_word = complete_word_list.index(i) #returns index of word to find
        nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[found_word-1]) #index-1 is the element to the left
        if found_word+1 < len(complete_word_list): #include a check to keep indices in range of list
            nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[found_word+1]) #index+1 is element to the right
print(nearby_words)
```

EDIT: 
As suggested, you could use a `try and except` catch to check if the element is in the list (`ValueError`) or if there are any adjacent elements to it (`IndexError`):

```
complete_word_list = ['3', 'May', '.', 'Bistritz', '.', 'Left', 'Munich', 'at', '8:35', 'P.', 'M.', ',', 'on', '1st', 'May', ',', 'arriving', 'atVienna', 'early', 'next', 'morning', ';', 'should', 'have', 'arrived', 'at', '6:46', ',', 'but', 'train', 'dracula', 'anhour', 'late']
dracula_list = ['dracula','Dracula']
nearby_words = []

for i in dracula_list:
    try:
        found_word = complete_word_list.index(i)
        nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[found_word-1])
        nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[found_word+1])
    except (ValueError, IndexError):
        print('this is either not in the list of there was not an adjacent element on either side.')
print(nearby_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`, so you get both the word and corresponding index:

```
for i, word in enumerate(complete_word_list):
    if word in dracula_list:
        if i: 
            nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[i-1])
        if i < len(complete_word_list) - 1:
            nearby_words.append(complete_word_list[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 right= [ complete_word_list[complete_word_list.index(i)+1] for i in dracula_list if i in complete_word_list and complete_word_list.index(i)+1<len(complete_word_list)]

 left= [ complete_word_list[complete_word_list.index(i)-1] for i in dracula_list if i in complete_word_list and complete_word_list.index(i)-1>=0]

 nearby_words = left + right
```

print

```
['train', 'anhour']
```